# using cURL to log redirects

Tags: bash, redirect, curl

Trying to develop a script that takes as an input a bunch of URLs and then tries to load the page and see if a redirect is actually happening and then logging the final URL.
I used this

```
REDIRECT=`curl -w "%{redirect_url}" --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0" http://m.cnbc.com`
echo "redirects to: ${REDIRECT}"
```

This code is working fine. But as soon as I change the URL to http://www.cnbc.com the script outputs the contents of the page source code on to the terminal. I am assuming this is happening because in case of http://www.cnbc.com there is no redirect, while in case of http://m.cnbc.com there is because the user agent is of desktop type.

Comment: how do I print the final URL to console without the page source in cases where the redirect is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-o /dev/null` to drop the output in the second case, and `-silent` so that curl will not display the progress:

```
# REDIRECT=`curl -w "%{redirect_url}" --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0" -o /dev/null -silent http://m.cnbc.com`
# echo "redirects to: ${REDIRECT}"
redirects to: http://www.cnbc.com/
# REDIRECT=`curl -w "%{redirect_url}" --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0" -o /dev/null -silent http://www.cnbc.com`
# echo "redirects to: ${REDIRECT}"                                                
redirects to:
```

Comment: I tested this and it works, just want to understand what is the idea behind using both "-o /dev/null" and "-silent"

Comment: @RaviGupta By default `curl` sends the data it fetches to the standard output, this is what you saw. Now you write it to `/dev/null` instead, which will just drop it. But now that it is not sending the data tou the standard output, `curl` displays the download progression instead. You may or may not want this, but `-silent` prevents it.